# jQuery Behave like Media Queries when Resizing Browser?

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I've been struggling with this for a while.  Basically I have a div (#memberrevealwrapper) that is a specific height unless the viewport is less than 790px in width, then it is another height. (It's a responsive web design)

Now, #memberrevealwrapper is animated using jQuery to make it function like a pull tab that comes from the top of the browser upon click and then click again and it rolls back up.

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '-75px'}, 200);
        $('#memberloginlink a').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '0' }, 500);
            },
            function(){
                $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '-75px'}, 500);
            }
        );
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();  

        if ( pageWidth <= 790 ) {

            $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '-147px' }, 200);
            $('#memberloginlink a').toggle(
                function(){
                    $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '0' }, 500);
                },
                function(){
                    $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '-147px'}, 500);
                }
            );

        }; 
    });

</script>
```

This works great until you resize the browser.  When you resize the browser, it doesn't find the new height and to readjust the height.

Here is the site in action: clients.januarycreative.com/PES.  I am referring to the "Member Login" tab at the top of the page.

Anyone know how I can get jQuery to refresh when the browser is resized? I've tried everything I know how, and have managed everything from cutting off the page to making the page bounce like a basketball many times in a row.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should listen to `resize` event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-run the code over again as the browser resizes. What you have up there just runs the code one on page load. You need a **loop** (technically an event that fires over and over again as the page resizes).

Here you go:

```
function updateSize() {
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();  

    if ( pageWidth <= 790 ) {
        $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '-147px' }, 200);
        $('#memberloginlink a').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '0' }, 500);
            },
            function(){
                $('#memberloginrevealwrapper').animate({ marginTop: '-147px'}, 500);
            }
        );
    }
}

$(window).resize(updateSize);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now to ask a stupid question, does this replace any existing code, or just goes at the end?

Comment: This works good! There is only two things:

When I size the page down it works great, but then when I resize the browser bigger, it doesn't go back to normal. I am guessing this is just a fix to make it say "on browser resize and it is wider than 791, go back to the original." But tying to manipulate the code to do it didn't work.

Second: when the page has been resized and you go to click on the tab, there is a very long delay before it does anything. Any idea on how to improve that?

It can all be seen here:  http://clients.januarycreative.com/pes/

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: I don't experience the first problem in Chrome or Safari on Mac OS X. As for the click on the tab, when I click the tabs, they do nothing at all, which makes since cause the URLs are all just "#". Could you describe the problem further?

Comment: For the first issue (not reverting back): It does the same in both Chrome and Safari on Mac. For instance, if you have the browser fairly wide (wider than 1200px) then size the browser smaller (less than 790px) it repositions great. However, if you were to resize the browser bigger (without refresh) from there back to more than 1200 wide, it cuts off the top. It's almost like it won't revert back to the top code (-75 px margin) and stays at the bottom part (-147px margin).

Comment: Second issue: It seems to be working on clicking the tab after resize, but to click again to make it roll back up there is a significant delay. Any ideas?

Thanks again for helping! I don't know alot about jQuery.

Comment: All your problems come from doing this in jQuery and not CSS with media queries. I'd honestly re-write it. I didn't realize you were doing so much responsive stuff.

Comment: Alrighty :) I will look for a way to do this using CSS animations hopefully!  Thanks again for all of your help!!

Comment: No need for animations really, just media queries.